# Procuro como salvar layout de um cxgrid (devexpress) usando StoreToStorage

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Em Delphi, um grid cxgrid da devexpress, procuro como salvar o layout no banco de dados. Possuo aqui funções para salvar em ini, mas isso produz vários arquivos na pasta e gostaria de salvar essas configurações no banco de dados

Para isso estava pensando em usar StoreToStorage, salvando no banco em string. Ou se não encontrar terei que jogar este ini no banco...

Alguém tem algum exemplo de código usando StoreToStorage?

Exemplo com INI Salvar

```
procedure TFrm_BI_Exemplo.actDoSaveExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
 grdPadraoCxDBTableView1.StoreToIniFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '/filtros/Teste.ini', true, [gsoUseFilter, gsoUseSummary]);
end
```

Exemplo com INI Carregar

```
procedure TFrm_BI_Exemplo.actDoLoadExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
     grdPadraoCxDBTableView1.RestoreFromIniFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '/filtros/teste.ini', true, false, [gsoUseFilter, gsoUseSummary]);
end;
```

Obrigado a todos

Comment: Faz tempo que não mexo com grids da Dev, mas devo ter algo com os samples deles. A noite, de casa dou uma olhada e te falo

Comment: @Caputo te agradeço pois ainda nao encontrei nenhum exemplo sobre StoreToStorage, ou usando StoreToStream mesmo. Aqui na hora de restaurar o grid fica todo tipo uma coluna, varios registros em branco. Comparando o que salva ini e estes em BLOB, me parece que ao salvar vem muito menos informação...

Comment: Quando possivel colocarei mais detalhes, mas pelo que vi este storetostorage nao funciona não. Para resolver usei StoreToIniFile salvando em arquivo ini e depois colocando as informacoes deste em um blob usando cdsNomeClientDataSetCAMPO.LoadFromFile('caminho ini'). Não gostaria de usar assim mas encontrei uma resposta no suporte da devexpress que diz:

Comment: "I am afraid that this functionality is not supported. The StoreToStream method saves layouts only in binary representation. We are aware of this limitation, but do not have plans to change it in the near future. This task is very specific and requires rewriting a lot of code from scratch.".

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q529793

Comment: Obs: Quando digo nao funciona seria na versao que uso Delphi 2006 e usando ExpressQuantumGrid Suite 6.38 . Quando possível atualizarei para ver.